# Groovy way to obtain number of seconds in a period

Tags: groovy

```
use(TimeCategory) {(1.year + 2.months + 3.hours).toMilliseconds() }
```

Any suggestions on how to get that in seconds (maintaining the level of grooviness)?

Comment: You wouldn't want to just divide it?

Comment: @doelleri: I seek to maintain the same readability of the above snippet. No arithmetic.

Comment: Those `+` operators don't count? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a closure to the `groovy.time.TimeDatumDependentDuration` class to hide the conversion to seconds:

```
TimeDatumDependentDuration.metaClass.toSeconds = { delegate.toMilliseconds() / 1000 }
```

and then:

```
use(TimeCategory) { (1.year + 2.months + 3.hours).toSeconds() }
```

will return seconds.